# Check my editor status

Tags: support, edits

Once upon a time on Stack Overflow I remember I was able to check my editor status. I.e. how many more edits I needed to be awarded editor badges, a summary of the proposed edits and the percentage of the accepted ones. I now cannot find that summary any more.

It may sound like a kind of stupid question, but can you point it out to me, if it still exists?

Answer (score 5):

It still exists, you can find that information in the new review queues. Even if you do not yet have enough reputation to do reviews, you can see your progress there:  https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats

Hover over the progress bar at the top right:

[image: progress bar]

to expand it to reveal a set of three more:

[image: progress bar expanded]

For the Strunk & White silver badge, look at the Copy Editor progress bar; you'll receive it when that indicates you've edited 80 posts.

Comment: I remember there was a badge for editing 80 questions?And I had indicated the number of questions to go for being awarded...does it still exist?

Comment: @Matteo: Look at the `Copy Editor` progress bar, it's still 80 for Strunk & White.

Comment: Got it!thks... ;)

Answer (score 1):

> How to get a summary of the proposed edits and the percentage of the accepted ones?

Go to [your suggestion activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/907921/matteo?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and click on any of your suggested edit and click on `(more)` you will find how many suggested edited approved and how many rejected.
For e.g. see [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1136630)

It shows:

> Matteo had 38 edit suggestions approved, and 5 edit suggestions rejected

That means you have edited 38 posts. Thus you can find the percentage of approved and rejected edits.

Comment: That does not count *unique* posts, which is what is needed for the badges. If 2 of those edits were for *one* question or answer, then for the purposes of gaining an editing badge, you've edited only 37 posts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - But someone can find the percentage of approved and rejected suggested edit. (As OP requires it.) :)

Comment: The OP wants to know their progress towards the editing badges. The number of accepted and rejected suggested edits is *not* enough to determine that. For one, if you reached 2k points but do not yet have an editing badge, then the approved count is not going to increase as you can edit posts directly. And the other point is that an editing badge counts only *one* edit per post, while the suggested edit count you linked to does not make that distinction. Granted, the progress I linked to does not give the count of accepted edits, which the OP *also* asked for indeed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - From OP's question *I.e. how many more edits I needed to be awarded editor badges, **a summary of the proposed edits and the percentage of the accepted ones*** Okay clearing the answer.