# Why haven't I received the Strunk & White badge yet? Receiving two values for my total edits

Tags: support, edits, badges, edit-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Check my editor status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157806/check-my-editor-status)

I thought I was going to get the Strunk and White badge this week on Stack but still haven't recieved it. I understand that there are some edits that count towards it and some that don't, but looking in two different places, I am told that I have make a different amount of edits.

- If, on SO, I go Users -> Editors -> All, I have 89 Edits.

Whereas,

- If I go [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/28670/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges-v1) and enter my SO ID, I have 94 Edits.

Could anybody tell me which is the accurate amount and maybe if it's possible to view the ACTUAL count of edits that make a difference to this and similar badges?

Comment: See [Check my editor status](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157806/157807#157807), find it on http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats and click on the progress bar.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, thats perfect.